# How to split long text by regex and get all parts?

Tags: regex, scala

I want to split a long scala file by the javadoc it contains, into some parts.

```
source split """(?s)\/\*\*(.*?)\*\/"""
```

works, but it will ignore all the javadoc it matchs.

How to get all parts?

For example:

```
/** package */
package test

/**
 * Class user
 */
class class User
```

It will be split into 4 parts:

```
/** package */
```

and

```
package test
```

and

```
/**
 * Class user
 */
```

and

```
case class User
```

How to do it?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

```
val source = """/** package */
package test

/**
 * Class user
 */
class class User"""

val R = """(?s)/\*\*.*?\*/"""

val x = R.r.findAllIn(source)
val y = source.split(R).toList.tail

val parts = x.toList.zip(y).flatMap(x => List(x._1, x._2))
```

As dhg said, using regex to solve such a problem is not recommended. It's slow and fragile.

Comment: Good. I tried `findAllIn` and `split`, and I didn't try them together.

Answer (score 1):

First: note that programming language syntax is not regular, and, thus, cannot actually be parsed with a regular expression.  It is context-free and, thus, you will require at least a context-free grammar to parse it.  You might be able to get by with something for simple cases (ie, a subset of the true syntax), but it is impossible to write an expression that will work in all cases.

That said, this works for the case you gave:

```
val split = source split """(?s)/\*\*|\*/"""
val parts =
  split.grouped(2).flatMap { 
    case Array(code,comment) => Seq(code, "/**" + comment + "*/")
    case code => code
  }
  .map(_.trim)
  .filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

The variable `parts` then contains the 4 strings you specified.

This expression will fail on, for example, an input where `/**` is contained inside a javadoc comment (`/** /** */`) or a is found between the quotation marks of a string literal (`val s = " /** "`).

Comment: Thanks, I know if I want to get the accurate result I need to use a parser, but simple regex is enough for my case.